# Why is there no gap between my two AlertDialog buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

In my AlertDialog, my Positive Button and Negative Button are "attached." I'm pretty sure there should be a gap between them. Can someone tell me why this is happening? I would be happy to provide any code. 
[Here is what my AlertDialog looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25iI4.png)

I have a custom View for the Body as well as the Title of my AlertDialog (I won't post that XML code because I don't think it's necessary, but let me know.) In MainActivity, I inflate my custom title and body Views, and override setPositive() and setNegative(), then I customize the color of my buttons using onShow().

Sorry for the convoluted code, but help would be much appreciated :). Here is my MainActivity:

```
public void openPrompt(View view){
    //builds and opens custom view with prompt.XML
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    EditText input = (EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    builder.setCancelable(true).setView(R.layout.customdialoglayout)
    .setNegativeButton("One", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CANCEL clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Two", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SET clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    //set title with custom XML layout view
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View titleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cutomtitlebar,null);
    builder.setCustomTitle(titleView);

    AlertDialog ad = builder.create();

    //change colors of background and buttons
    ad.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            Window view = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getWindow();

            view.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrompt);
           Button negButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButton));
            negButton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButtonText));

            Button posButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            posButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButton));
            posButton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButtonText));
        }
    });


    ad.show();


}
```

**EDIT** Here is my XML I used for setView():

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="CUSTOM TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: please, show us you layout.xml, because there you could add some gap space.

Comment: Android Studio got nothing with your question. Try to use relevant tags only.

Comment: this answer work for me
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/59086497/8905812

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why should there be a gap between them? The positive and negative buttons get their layout dimensions from the `AlertDialog` class and does not, from what I can recall, have any margin in between the buttons.

In order to add a margin, you can either make your own buttons and not use the positive and negative buttons from the `AlertDialog` or you can add margin to the buttons in a similar manner that you styled the buttons.

```
ad.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            Window view = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getWindow();

            view.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrompt);
           Button negButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButton));
            negButton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPromptButtonText));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params.setMargins(20,0,0,0);
            negButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow, that worked great. I thought that was the problem, but when I used the "default" AlertDialog, it had a gap between buttons so I thought maybe I'd done something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer! 
"Why should there be a gap between them" ?
Because when you use longer text then just "Yes", "No" or RTL languages there is 0 gap between them

Comment: Please give me more details about this, Which files change or not

Answer (score 17):

Why don't we improvise if we need a gap between your buttons? Instead of using the negative button you can use the neutral button. This is because the positive and the negative are inseparable, But the neutral and positive works fine one in the far right side and one in the far left side. So just change negative button to neutral and it works. See code below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(preview.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Title here");
                    builder.setMessage("message on dialog here");
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setNeutralButton("Name of button N", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           //your code here
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Name of button P", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //your code here
                        }
                    });
```

This is an example which is working perfectly to me, from your code you can edit it like below:

```
builder.setCancelable(true).setView(R.layout.customdialoglayout)
.setNeutralButton("One", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CANCEL clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
})
.setPositiveButton("Two", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SET clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: but, I want three button, and there is unwanted gaps.

Comment: I just discovered this behavior by trial and error. The visual effect is actually much more appealing to me, because I'd like more separation between cancel and proceed options. Accidental touches are a drag.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this for all your AlertDialog's in your app is to change the styles.xml

Add a custom theme to your AlertDialog's

```
//Kotlin code
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom))

//Java Code
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
```

in the styles.xml

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
//whichever parent theme you want to use here 
//add these 2 to allow all APIs
<item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveAlertButtonStyle</item>
<item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveAlertButtonStyle</item>

//change the marginStart of the Positive button to put a gap between the buttons
//you can also change text color and background etc. here
<style name="PositiveAlertButtonStyle">
<item name="android:layout_marginStart">10dp</item>
```