# Alert dialog buttons are too close

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, material-design

I see this thing with Alert dialog's buttons touching (there is no space between them).

[image]

This happens regardless of the theme being used.. Code:

```
builder.setTitle(R.string.sign_in_title);
builder.setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_in, (dialog, id) -> {
            //Todo
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());
builder.create().show();
```

App theme inherits:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I tried to build a minimum project setup just with Alert.Dialog and I see the same thing..

Any ideas what is going on or how to fix it?

Edit: I'm aware that I can change Alert's theme to yield different results but that also implies that I won't have uniform buttons across my app (i.e. green filled with white text)

Comment: The problem with this was in mixing android.app and androidx.appcompact.app dialog so the fix was to use only androidx.appcompact.app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change imported class for **AlertDialog** from Supported Library:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is more of a lucky coincidence, doesn't work for me. You should use androidx components whenever possible, so at least this answer is not misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Use the theme for your alertDialog,

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Work fine for me**

```
  <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
```

> Just call "DialogTheme" to use in your dialog activity

Comment: Add closing style </style> and after pasting this into styles you have to use this style in your dialog 

val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.DialogTheme)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your style by this

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I see but that's not quite according to the guidelines: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/ isn't it?